# How to make Android application should not exit

Tags: android

Is there any option in android like we should give to user to close
the application , i.e using forcestop or uninstall.

I want to create app in such a mean that once install the user should
not uninstall and should not stop.

Is there any way to implement service to run allways in background.

Comment: Is this a poor attempt at covering up some sort of malicious app?

Comment: Not necesarily, it can be for a usecase were your users are given the device for a certain period of time to use a specific app and then give it back. You would want to be sure that they don´t do other things with the device. Think of museums and so on.

Answer (score 9):

This is not allowed by Android APIs. The user will always be able to force stop your app, uninstall it or even disable it by booting in safe mode.

Comment: "safe mode"? You use a root shell to disable a package. pm disable com.example.foobar

Comment: No need to use a root shell. If you hold down the Home key during boot, Android will ignore all user installed packages. This is a safe way for users to uninstall applications that are misbehaving.